# Couldn't find a package.json file error when deploying in Netlify

Tags: json, deployment, netlify

I was deploying my project to Netlify, and before deploying, went to **Deploy settings > Build & deploy > Continuous deployment > Build settings** and set the build command to `CI= npm run build`. Then I went to **Deploy settings > Build & deploy > Environment > Environment variables** and made a new value called `CI` with a value of `false`.

After that, I went to **Deploys > Trigger deploy > Clear cache and deploy site** to deploy. But then when it was deploying, it gave me and error saying:

```
1:38:12 PM: error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/opt/build/repo"
```

I would really appreciate anyone helping me with this issue, thank you!

Comment: Your `CI` from the environment variables is not used, because you set it to empty with `CI= npm run build`.

Comment: @knittl should I remove that then?

Comment: I don't know why you have added it, but it is setting CI to empty for the npm process.